# ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' while import request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I get an error while trieng to import py package "requests"

While trieng to import py package

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections
```

in python 3.10.6

```
import requests
```

**what i already tried**

add a string

```
from _collections_abc import Mapping
```

```
try:
    from collections.abc import Mapping
except ImportError:
    from collections import Mapping
```

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
from collections.abc import Sequence
```

Full

````
  File "C:\Users\Никита\Desktop\python\Projects\sandoxWithSnakes\sandbox.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .connection import is_connection_dropped
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .wait import wait_for_read
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\wait.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .selectors import (
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\selectors.py", line 14, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple, Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)```

but it's not work:(

**why this error occurs and how to solve?**
````

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: updated* add a full Traceback

Comment: I cannot reproduce, my version of Python is 3.10.8 and `from collections.abc import Mapping` works normally.

Comment: The used "urllib3" library is outdated, maybe an update would help. The "Mapping" class was moved to "collections.abc" in Python 3.3, backward compatibility measures were removed in 3.10.